# Shopify - Product Variant API

Tags: shopify, variant

Is there a way to create multiple product variants for single product with one POST call?

I know a single product variant can be made with:

```
POST /admin/products/#{id}/variants.json
{
   "variant": 
   {
      "option1": "Default Title",
      "price": "1.00"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to execute a single POST to create multiple variants for the same product id?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here is a node sample for adding new variants to an existing product. The caveat is that you have to populate the variants array with the ids of the variants you want to keep:

```
var https = require('https');

var cred = new Buffer("xxx:yyy").toString('base64');

var headers = {Authorization: "Basic "+cred, "Content-Type": "application/json"};
var productId = 1925263361;
var options = {
  host: 'kotntest1.myshopify.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/admin/products/'+productId +'.json',
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: headers
};

// Setup the request.  The options parameter is
// the object we defined above.
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf-8');

  var responseString = '';

  res.on('data', function(data) {
    responseString += data;
    //console.log(data);
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    var resultObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
    console.dir(resultObject);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  // TODO: handle error.
  console.log(e);
});

var product = {
  product:{
    id: productId, 
    variants: [
      {
        id:5991257025 //existing variant id
      },
      {
        id:5991257089 //existing variant id
      },
      {
        id:19762423495 //existing variant id
      },
      // new variant details
      {
        title:'v4', // new variant details
        option1: 'green',
        option2: "Honda", 
        option3: 'Civic'
      },{
        title:'v5',
        option1: 'pink',
        option2: "Honda", 
        option3: 'Civic'
      },{
        title:'v6',
        option1: 'yellow',
        option2: "Honda", 
        option3: 'Civic'
      },{
        title:'v7',
        option1: 'brown',
        option2: "Honda", 
        option3: 'Civic'
      }
      ]
    }

};

req.write(JSON.stringify(product));
req.end();
```

Comment: Thanks bk for the response but my issue is that the product itself already exists.  Am looking to add new variants to the existing product so don't think the POST on the product API is going to work.  Industry I work in is apparel and it's not uncommon for designers to constantly be adding colors and/or sizes to an existing product.  That's why in my example I was using calling the Product Variant API.

Comment: just use a PUT. See my new sample